# Django: How to set default language in admin on login

Tags: django, django-admin, django-middleware

I'm saving an user's default language in his user profile and on login I want to set the admin's default language to it.

One possibility I was thinking of is using a middleware, but I think if I do it on `process_request` I will not see an user object there since this is processed AFTER the middleware, so I could only set it after the next request!
Any solutions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sad thing is Django doesn't send any signals on Login/Logout (apparently there's a ticket open for that at http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5612).

But looking around I found a rather simple and elegant solution for implementing signals on login/logout without touching Django's code: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/hooking-into-djangos-login-and-logout-two-approaches/

Comment: That [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5612) was fixed, we can now enjoy of login/logout signals! :)

Comment: Auth signal documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals

Answer (score 0):

You can do follow:
In templates/admin/login.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "{% url 'setLangueDefault' %}",
                    dataType : 'JSON',
                    success : function(data) {
                        //
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

In frontend/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('frontend.views',
    ...
    url(r'^set-language-default/$', views.setLangueDefault, name='setLangueDefault'),
    ....
```

)

In frontend/views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
...
def setLangueDefault(request):
    language = settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
    if hasattr(request, 'session'):
        if 'django_language' in request.session:
            language = request.session['django_language']
    if language:
        request.session['django_language'] = language
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = {'status' : 0, 'info' : 'done'}
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(message))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Note config default language in settings.py
Exp: LANGUAGE_CODE = 'vi'